# Name the labels according to loop

Tags: wpf, vb.net

There are 5 labels named as lblP1, lblP2, lblP3, lblP4, lblP5. I want to display text in those labels according to Do Until Loop. **(I'm using wpf with vb.net)**

```
Dim x as integer=1
Do Until x=5
lblP(x).Text = x
x=x+1
Loop
```

But this code doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Comment: `lblP(x).Text = x.ToString()`.  Your code doesn't work because `x` is an `integer`, and `Text` is a  `string`.  These are incompatible types. `ToString` converts `x` in to a `string`.  This assumes you already have your controls in a list named `lblP`, that may not be true, in which case, follow Zaggler's instructions below..

Comment: You need to find the controls first **Controls.Find**.. right now the way you have it won't work because you can't reference a control the way you have it. Also I would answer this but you don't give credit when someone helps you...

Comment: As a side note, you should say exactly what you mean by "Does not work".  Does it not compile, throw an exception, or do something else?

Comment: But error message display as "lblP is not declared". Plz help me @Zaggler or anyone